# Sprites don't follow bodies movements. PhysicsConnector + Update Rotation

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I am using:

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));
```

When the body interact with another it moves correctly, but the sprite moves oddly.

The image show this situation.

[image]

How I correct that?

--
Code:

```
Sprite sp = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.box_region, vbom);
Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, sp, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sp, body, true, true));
```

Comment: Is this everything you do with this sprite/body? No more code to move them? Does this happen after the collision? Are you sure that sprite has correct size (it may be bigger than you think if you did not prepare it correctly, and you do not see it because of transparency)

Comment: It is put in scene by SimpleLevelLoader.
I changed values of FixtureDef to test, but always show the same error.
There were UpdateHandler and I overwrite of isCulled(), these codes was removed. The error continues. 
This object moves when other objects interact with him.
The Sprite have no transparency.

Comment: I have found a old PhysicsConnector class. There is another constructor with parameters pUpdateLinearVelocity and pUpdateAngularVelocity. This resolved my problem. In new versions I continue with the problem.